# Is struct data returned from web3 guaranteed to be in the correct order?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-design, struct

I have this solidity struct

```
struct Prices {
    uint sell_price;        // wei
    uint target_price;      // primary
    uint penalty_price;     // wei
}
Prices public prices
```

In truffle when I do `contract.prices()` I retrieve an array `[sell_price, target_price, penalty_price]` , the order which they are listed in the struct. I wanted to know if this order is guaranteed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**

The getter function that Solidity generates uses the order listed in the struct.  Solidity would generate a function of the following form:

```
function prices() constant returns (uint sell_price, uint target_price, uint penalty_price) {
  sell_price = prices.sell_price;
  target_price = prices.target_price;
  penalty_price = prices.penalty_price;
}
```

Here's the ABI and see that the `outputs` have a specific order:

```
[
  {
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "prices",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "sell_price",
        "type": "uint256"
      },
      {
        "name": "target_price",
        "type": "uint256"
      },
      {
        "name": "penalty_price",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "type": "function"
  }
]
```

---

Additionally, a more complex example of a getter from
http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#getter-functions

```
contract Complex {
    struct Data {
        uint a;
        bytes3 b;
        mapping (uint => uint) map;
    }
    mapping (uint => mapping(bool => Data[])) public data;
}
```

It will generate a function of the following form:

```
function data(uint arg1, bool arg2, uint arg3) returns (uint a, bytes3 b) {
    a = data[arg1][arg2][arg3].a;
    b = data[arg1][arg2][arg3].b;
}
```

*Note that the mapping in the struct is omitted because there is no good way to provide the key for the mapping.*

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.**

The ABI is a collection of fixed-length arguments in a specific order. The elements will be reliably/consistently ordered.

Hope it helps.